# Show all columns when using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, pivot

im working to build a dynamic table (header from table and cells from a table)
this is my table

```
select rrc.Text , rch.Name
from RateColumnHeaders rch inner join
RateRowColumn rrc on rch.RateColumnHeadersId=rrc.RateColumnHeadersId

Text    Name
------------------------
test    Account Type
test2   Account Type
test3   Account Type
test4   Account Type
lorem1  Program
lorem2  Program
lorem3  Program
.           .
.           .
.           .
```

and after using pivot method i got that result but in mean time i need to show all the columns not only the max(text)
how i can achieve that please ?

for me i want to show result like that

```
Account Type |  Program |.....
test         |  lorem1  
test2        |  lorem2  
test3        |  lorem3
```

.
.
.
this is my pivot query

```
select * from (
select rrc.Disclaimer,rch.Name,rrc.Text 
from RateRowColumn rrc 
inner join RateColumnHeaders rch 
on rrc.RateColumnHeadersId=rch.RateColumnHeadersId
) s pivot ( max(text) for name in ( [Account Type],[Program]) ) pvt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a pivot (I don't think).  I think you just want to list the values in each group as a list.

You can use conditional aggregation and `row_number()`:

```
select max(case when name = 'Account Type' then text end) as account_type,
       max(case when name = 'Program' then text end) as program,
       . . .
from (select rrc.Text, rch.Name,
             row_number() over (partition by rch.Name order by rrc.Text) as seqnum
      select rrc.Text, rch.Name
      from RateColumnHeaders rch inner join
           RateRowColumn rrc 
           on rch.RateColumnHeadersId = rrc.RateColumnHeadersId
     ) rrc
group by seqnum;
```